# Email entire post contents

Tags: posts, comments, email

We're a small newspaper with our archives put into a localhost WordPress web server in-house. I'm looking for some sort of plugin that might allow the reporters to, say, click a button that would email them the contents of the entire post to themselves (not just a link, as the server is not connected to the rest of the world). Any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look on the following plugin for this purpose:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email/

For this plugin to work, your localhost WordPress web server need to connect your SMTP server for sending email. Follow the instruction on the link below to install the plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email/installation/

Cheers.